# How exactly does "inc" in assembly works here?

Tags: assembly, x86

I am learning assembly and I am not sure about this little thing here.
So I've got this piece of code here

```
mov DWORD PTR [ebp-4],0X0
cmp DWORD PTR [ebp-4],0X9
.
.
.
lea eax,[ebp-4]
inc DWORD PTR [eax]
...
```

and I am not sure why exactly do I have to use the "lea" and "eax" here. If I understand it correctly, [ebp-4] points to int(4 bytes) with the value of 0. Could I increment it directly without using "eax" reigster ? 
Also, obviously I can directly compare the value in [ebp-4] with value "9" so why couldn't I increment it in the same fashion ?

Thanks for every hint.

Comment: Yes you could write it as `inc dword ptr [ebp-4]`. Maybe `eax` is needed later with the address, so it's useful to write it this way.

Comment: there's no comparison here. You must look at what will be used later

Comment: There's not enough context, you should post the whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

```
lea eax,[ebp-4]      ; eax = ebp-4
inc DWORD PTR [eax]  ;decrease dword at location ebp-4 by one.
```

If you had written:

```
inc DWORD PTR [ebp-4]
```

It would have done the exact same thing.
There is no need to use `EAX` here, you can use complex addressing anywhere you can address memory at no cost (other than perhaps instruction length).

Perhaps the code is reusing `eax` a lot further down, or perhaps you're looking at unoptimized code.